# `saveRelations` returning `null`

Tags: plugin-development, relations

I'm using the `saveRelations` method in the `RelationsService` to save entry relationships in a plugin I'm working on. Everything is working as expected, however, `saveRelations` is returning `null` on success, which seems odd.

Here is a portion of the code I'm working with:

```
public function addCategoryRelation(CategoryModel $category, EntryModel $entry)
{
    $field        = $craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('handle');
    $handle       = $field->handle;
    $relations    = $category->$handle;
    $relationsIds = [];

    /**
     * Get the ids for the relations.
     */
    foreach ($relations as $entry) {
        $relationsIds[] = $entry->id;
    }

    if (!in_array($entry->id, array_values($relationsIds))) {
        $relationsIds[] = $entry->id;
        return craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $category, $relationsIds);
    } else {
        return [
            'error' => 'Entry already saved.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `null` back simply because the [`saveRelations()` method](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/RelationsService.php#L29) doesn't actually return anything.

If you need to return `true` from `addCategoryRelation` if the relations are successfully saved, or possibly an error message (or `false`) if they aren't, you can consider wrapping the call to `saveRelations()` in a try/catch block – something like this should work:

```
public function addCategoryRelation(CategoryModel $category, EntryModel $entry)
{
    ...
    if (in_array($entry->id, array_values($relationsIds))) {
        return [
            'error' => 'Entry already saved.',
        ];
    }
    try {
        $relationsIds[] = $entry->id;
        return craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $category, $relationsIds);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong – return `false` or an error message, log the exception?
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```